# passing text with \n as one argument in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i have a file called file1 containing the following

```
firstname lastname location etc
second line
third line
```

i am using this code

```
read a b c < file1
echo $a $b $c
```

the output i am getting is

```
firstname lastname location etc
```

so my program is taking

```
a = firstname 
b = lastname
c= location etc
```

how can i get my program to take

```
c= location etc second line third line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-d` flag in `read`:

```
read -d '' a b c < file1

echo "$c"
location etc
second line
third line
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your query you want to have everything in one line.

```
# read file in one variable
c=`cat file1`
# keep everything in a separate line
echo "$c"
# put everything in one line
echo $c
```

The last `echo` will produce the output you have in your question:

`firstname lastname location etc second line third line`